# Are most staff at Brussels airport Dutch or French-speaking?

Tags: airports, belgium, languages, bru

I'm going to Brussels airport and will require some special assistance in addition to the usual check-in procedures.

Knowing both Dutch and French adequately, I'd like to know which language most staff mainly speak, so I know which one to use by default.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if fluency in Dutch, French, and English is a standard requirement for employment in the airport.

Comment: What a great question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Brussels, both Dutch and French are considered the main languages. Logically, it should be about 50/50. However, Brussels Airport is located in Zaventem, which is **not in Brussels**, but in the Flemish (Dutch-speaking) area (Flanders). So **the chance of finding native Dutch-speaking staff should be higher.** (again, in theory, as I don't know the staff).

Last time I went, staff spoke Dutch to each other as well.

Staff there also certainly speak at least basic English.

I'd speak Dutch by default in Brussels airport, but really it depends on which language you are more comfortable with talking. If you doubt, you can always ask them before you start the conversation. I'm sure they'll appreciate it.

If you're talking about check-in service, it might depend on your airline, though. I remember China Airlines staff at the check-in mostly spoke Chinese and English one time. This is not the case for airport staff.

Comment: I'm flying on Tui Belgium (former Jetairfly)

Comment: @Crazydre It's impossible to tell for sure. Maybe you can notice what language they speak before you talk to them. My advice is to speak the language you are most comfortable with of both. Otherwise, maybe somebody else can answer with more insights.

Answer (score 5):

Everything Kevin said is true, and I can tell you from lots of experience that they are almost all native Dutch speakers, so go with Dutch if you know it!